# how to make AVAudioPlayer follow ringer volume not media volume like whatsapp

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

i have AVAudioPlayer which is working fine in normal condition. (ringer volume max and media volume max)

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

in .m

```
NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"asd" ofType:@"m4a"]];
NSError *error = nil;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:beepURL error:&error];
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

case 1 if ringer volume is low player sound doesnt work which is fine.

case 2 if media volume is low and ringer volume is max sound doesnt work.

this functionality is working in whatsapp also

[image: case 1]
[image: case 2]

Comment: maybe MPVolumeView can help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/index.html

Comment: tried didnt work in same scenario